# Why can I not access this method from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app where I'm trying to make a GET request to my API using Retrofit2. I have copied some code online that allows me to add the access token to the body of the request as this is how my API is setup. Following the code online, the author is able to call the `api` variable from a different class but I am unable to.

Here is the class the `api` variable is defined:
**cCustomerService.java**

```
package com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.OauthConstant;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.service.CustomerService;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okio.Buffer;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

import static com.example.dentdevils.MainActivity.access;
import static com.example.dentdevils.MainActivity.mypreference;

public class cCustomerService {

    public final CustomerService api;
    private Context mContext;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
                    mContext.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                            .add("access_token", sharedPreferences.getString(access, ""))
                            .build();

                    String postBodyToString = bodyToString(request.body());
                    postBodyToString += ((postBodyToString.length() > 0) ? "&" : "") + bodyToString(formBody);
                    request = requestBuilder.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"), postBodyToString))
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();

    public static String bodyToString(final RequestBody requestBody) {
        try {
            final RequestBody copy = requestBody;
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            if (copy != null) {
                copy.writeTo(buffer);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "didn't work";
        }
    }

    public cCustomerService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(OauthConstant.DATA_SERVER_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(CustomerService.class);
    }

}
```

As you can see I set the api variables value at the bottom.

Now I want to access it in the following class:
**ViewCustomers.Java**

```
package com.example.dentdevils;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.OauthConstant;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client.cCustomerService;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.response.CustomerResponse;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.service.CustomerService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static com.example.dentdevils.MainActivity.access;
import static com.example.dentdevils.MainActivity.mypreference;
import static com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client.cCustomerService.bodyToString;


public class ViewCustomers extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_customers);

        CustomerService customerService = api.create(CustomerService.class);

        Call<List<CustomerResponse>> callArray = customerService.getCustomers();
        callArray.enqueue(new Callback<List<CustomerResponse>>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CustomerResponse>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<CustomerResponse>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    List<CustomerResponse> customers = response.body();
                    customers.forEach(customer -> System.out.println(customer.getName()));
                } else {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Failed!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CustomerResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG", t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

As you can see I reference the api variable on this line `CustomerService customerService = api.create(CustomerService.class);` but I get an error saying it `cannot resolve symbol 'api'`. Like I said the author of the post has his setup exactly like mine so why isn't mine working? I added the relevant imports and I still can't access it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could either declare api in ViewCustomers (same way like in cCustomerService) or make the field variable in cCustomerService static or (prefered method) create an object of cCustomerService an reference api like `(new cCustomerService()).api.create(CustomerService.class)`

Comment: Could you also post the link to the article.

Comment: @saurabhgupta https://androidpedia.net/en/tutorial/1132/retrofit2#retrofit-with-okhttp-interceptor - Under the Simple GET Request heading